# Make XAML visible under Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I know it may seem like a simple question, but I can't for the life of me find how to make a grid have the ability to see through it. I have already tried making the background transparent, but that does not work. I have a textbox and a picture in XAML, (everything else in my program, including the grid, are made programatically), but I no longer see the textbox or the image, i just see the grid. Any Help?

> XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWin" x:Class="WhackaMoleReal.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="421.378" Width="624.929">
    <Grid>
        <Image Margin="353,156,-131,-58" Source="mole2.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Can You Catch the Mole?" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="79" Width="497" FontFamily="SimHei" FontSize="40"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

> C#:

```
        Grid grid_Main = new Grid();

// Create Grid \\
            MainWin.Content = grid_Main;
            grid_Main.Height = MainWindowHeight;
            grid_Main.Width = MainWindowWidth;
            grid_Main.Background = Brushes.Transparent;


                // Fill Grid \\
                int RowCount = 0;
                int ColumnCount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i <= NumofImages; i++)
                {
                    Image newImage = HoleImage();
                    if (RowCount < NumberofRows)
                    {
                        if (ColumnCount < NumberOfColumns)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ColumnCount: " + ColumnCount.ToString());
                            Grid.SetRow(newImage, RowCount);
                            Grid.SetColumn(newImage, ColumnCount);
                            grid_Main.Children.Add(newImage);
                            ColumnCount++;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            RowCount++;
                            ColumnCount = 0;
                            Grid.SetRow(newImage, RowCount);
                            Grid.SetColumn(newImage, ColumnCount);
                            grid_Main.Children.Add(newImage);
                            ColumnCount++;
                            Console.WriteLine("RowCount: " + RowCount.ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that adds `grid_Main` to the Windows Grid

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I just added it, it's under "//Create Grid"

Comment: Then you problem is you are replacing the the current windows content (Grid,Image,TextBox) with your new grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are replacing the the current windows content (Grid,Image,TextBox) with your new grid(grid_Main).

It looks like you just want to add the new Grid (grid_Main) to the existing Window Grid

**Xaml:**

```
<Window x:Name="MainWin" x:Class="WhackaMoleReal.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="421.378" Width="624.929">
    <Grid x:Name="Content_Grid">
        <Image Margin="353,156,-131,-58" Source="mole2.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Can You Catch the Mole?" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="79" Width="497" FontFamily="SimHei" FontSize="40"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
Grid grid_Main = new Grid();

// Create Grid \\
Content_Grid.Children.Add(grid_Main);
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can keep the image that is in the XAML from getting stretched out?

Comment: Maybe `Stretch="Uniform"`, cant really tell without seeing what you are seeing

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I'm just going to remove the image, it looks fine with out it. Thanks for the Help :)